# swf to quicktime

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, export, quicktime

I have a flash file that contains actionscript3 in it. I am trying to export my file as a .mov to play in quicktime. Sometimes it will work, then if I make a change to my file (moving a few frames around, but not changing the script at all), it will then export an empty file. 
Does any one have any tips on what I can do? Maybe how to export a quicktime.

I am trying to figure out if I can bring a file with actionscript into After Effects?

Thanks,
Rachel

Comment: you can export a quicktime file from flash (even with actionscript generated content) which you can use in After Effects and other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple software solutions out there that can do a clean conversion for you.
The one I used most is [Sothink's Swf to Video Converter](http://www.sothink.com/product/swftovideoconverter/index.htm). After a couple tests, I was surprised that it handled even actionscripted events seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of one for a mac by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the root to your question: "I am trying to figure out if I can bring a file with actionscript into After Effects?"

No. When flash exports a video, it exports the literal frame by frame animation of the timeline, no execution of scripts, not even any movie clips on stage actually play like they would in a running swf. This is because video is not a running program, just literally video, frame by frame of what pixels should show what colors.

That's probably why you are getting a blank video, did "moving a couple frames around" involve reducing the Main Timeline to not having any real part in the animation, maybe relying more on movieclips playing? Because then you'd definitely just get a blank video.

If you want scripted animation caught as video then the best thing to do is learn the After Effects based scripting, I believe it is called Expressions, and it is based on Javascript (much like AS2 is). If you want an actual flash file's scripted animation then you will have to capture it as it plays on screen, using software such as Camtasia.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to export from Flash Professional Authoring via **File > Export > Export Movie** and choosing the Quicktime option. Since version CS3, Flash can export actionscript generated content as Quicktime.

See this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186614/is-export-movie-as-png-sequence-for-movies-with-actionscript-animation-possible).