# Render each frame as a single image

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, animation, flash-cs4

Just curious, can flash take each frame and export it out as a image ? In my case, I want to create sprite images for a flashdevelop project using blitting. Of course I know there is a solution for this. like copy and paste each shape into a image editor such as photoshop and turn them into png's. But I am just seeing if there is a simpler means of doing so.

Comment: Are you looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186614/is-export-movie-as-png-sequence-for-movies-with-actionscript-animation-possible/2189270#2189270?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [BitmapData.draw()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()). You can listen to frame events and programmatically spit out bitmaps from within Flash (draw the stage onto a bitmap, lather, rinse, repeat). Combine this with a PNG encoder and you can automate the entire process very easily.

Answer (score 3):

there is an export function with flash too, so if you animate or draw your objects to stage you can export it as in image sequence (file->export->export movie-> jpeg, GIF, png etc).